# Find the name of people who live at the same postal code, with flight delaying between 1 and 5

Tags: mysql, sql

My current code is

```
select u.name , u.postalcode 
FROM user u, flightdetails f, userscan s 
WHERE deppdelay > 1 AND deppdelay <5 AND f.ticketid = s.ticketid AND s.userid = u.userid AND u.postalcode IN 
(SELECT postalcode FROM user GROUP BY postalcode HAVING COUNT(postalcode) > 1) 
ORDER BY postalcode;
```

The output is this

| name | postalcode |
| --- | --- |
| Lee Jie Xuan | 120338 |
| Nicholas Sim | 120338 |
| Jasper Tan | 120359 |
| Nicholas Tan | 120359 |
| William Lee | 120381 |
| Brandon Cheong | 120381 |
| Choo Jia Yang Kiron | 120453 |
| Christopher Ang | 120453 |
| Ivan Goh | 120460 |
| Nelson Loo | 120460 |
| Kew Rui Hern | 680623 |
| Philbert Han | 680767 |
| Carter Reilly | 680790 |
| Phlip Wong | 680790 |
| Glen Ang | 681660 |
| Ignatius Ng | 681660 |

However the expected outcome i Would like is duplicate values with distinct names. However, there are postal codes in my code that do not have duplicates.
Is there any recommended way to go about doing this?

P.S on the excel file, the postal codes that are displayed once has duplicate postal codes, however the other name has a flight delay not between 1 and 5.

Expected outcome:

| name | postalcode |
| --- | --- |
| Lee Jie Xuan | 120338 |
| Nicholas Sim | 120338 |
| Jasper Tan | 120359 |
| Nicholas Tan | 120359 |
| William Lee | 120381 |
| Brandon Cheong | 120381 |
| Choo Jia Yang Kiron | 120453 |
| Christopher Ang | 120453 |
| Ivan Goh | 120460 |
| Nelson Loo | 120460 |
| Carter Reilly | 680790 |
| Phlip Wong | 680790 |
| Glen Ang | 681660 |
| Ignatius Ng | 681660 |

I have actually managed to get rid of the single postal codes by using GROUP BY & HAVING COUNT (postalcode) > 1, however, because of the group by, I have distinct names missing.

```
select distinct u.name , u.postalcode 
FROM user u, flightdetails f, userscan s 
WHERE deppdelay > 1 AND deppdelay <5 AND f.ticketid = s.ticketid AND s.userid = u.userid AND u.postalcode IN 
(SELECT postalcode FROM user GROUP BY postalcode HAVING COUNT(postalcode) > 1) 
GROUP BY postalcode 
HAVING COUNT(postalcode) >1;
```

Below is the o/p;

| name | postalcode |
| --- | --- |
| Lee Jie Xuan | 120338 |
| Nicholas Tan | 120359 |
| William Lee | 120381 |
| Choo Jia Yang Kiron | 120453 |
| Ivan Goh | 120460 |
| Phlip Wong | 680790 |
| Ignatius Ng | 681660 |

Sample data (user)

| userid (key) | name | postalcode | phonenum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 95559 | Uriah Ferry | 238859 | 83792072 |
| 32971 | Mariah lupin | 238859 | 81343214 |

Sample data (flightdetails)

| ticketid (key) | depddelay (departure delay) |
| --- | --- |
| KED100001 | 2 |
| KED100002 | 3 |

userscan  (relationship)

| ticketid | userid |
| --- | --- |
| KED100001 | 95559 |
| KED100002 | 32971 |

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure, sample input data, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Yeah having the input tables is likely to help the understanding here.

Comment: I think you need to put WHERE deppdelay > 1 AND deppdelay <5 in your subquery too, or the COUNT will also include irrelevant users

Comment: The sentence _"I have actually managed to get rid of the single postal codes by using, however [..]"_ seems to be missing something (the _what_ you're using).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this does the trick

```
SELECT
usr.name , usr.postalcode
FROM flightdetails AS fd
INNER JOIN userscan AS uss ON fd.ticketid = uss.ticketid
INNER JOIN user AS usr ON uss.userid = usr.userid
WHERE fd.deppdelay > 1 AND fd.deppdelay <5
AND usr.postalcode IN
(
SELECT
usr.postalcode
FROM flightdetails AS fd
INNER JOIN userscan AS uss ON fd.ticketid = uss.ticketid
INNER JOIN user AS usr ON uss.userid = usr.userid
WHERE fd.deppdelay > 1 AND fd.deppdelay <5
GROUP BY usr.postalcode
HAVING COUNT(usr.postalcode) > 1
)
ORDER BY postalcode;
```

If the output format is less important, you can also do something like this, without the subquery:

```
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(usr.name) as usernames,
usr.postalcode
FROM flightdetails AS fd
INNER JOIN userscan AS uss ON fd.ticketid = uss.ticketid
INNER JOIN user AS usr ON uss.userid = usr.userid
WHERE fd.deppdelay > 1 AND fd.deppdelay <5
GROUP BY usr.postalcode
HAVING COUNT(usr.name) > 1
ORDER BY postalcode;
```

In that case, watch out for truncated results, MySQL will return 1024 chars in the GROUP_CONCAT by default

Comment: Nice one! Thank you so much! So basically the delay has to be in the nested statement as well to filter out the unnecessary users, based on one of the comments?

Comment: See my initial comment.. ;). If you don't mind that the usernames are in a grouped column, you could do it even easier. I'll add that alternative too